# Position row at bottom of Jumbotron/container

Tags: css

```
<div class="container-full-bg" style="background-image:url('background.jpg');">
<div class="container special">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row push-to-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p style="color:#fff;"><span style="color:red;font-size:100px;"> 1</span>/10</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="xxx"/>
```

So I have the above code and it works, but the only thing is that i'd like to position the row/col-md-6's at the bottom of the container. I tried applying position:absolute; and bottom:0; to the row, but that'll just position it to the bottom of the page and put "1/10" left. I'd like it to stay inside the container, and I can't find the fix!

What am I missing?

Edit: I also tried giving the parent div an absolute position and then apply absolute en bottom:0; to the row, but that still won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give `position: relative` to the `.container` or the `.jumbotron` element. This way you can set `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` to the `.push-to-bottom` div.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment you could do it like this:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-color: inherit;
}
.container-full-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container-full-bg .container,
.container-full-bg .container .jumbotron {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
  position: relative
}
.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.push-to-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thepio/Lnacr8kn/

Comment: Thanks! That kind of worked, but the "1/10" will float left, I made a Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/knuhgLos/

Comment: Where exactly would you want it positioned?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/aaWmHct.png Just like this, but then positioned at the bottom. So still in the Bootstrap grid!

Comment: I've edited my answer for it to use basic Bootstrap grid and make it stay within those lines.

Comment: Sorry, yes it did. Thanks for the answer. :) +1